# LWJGL texture render shifted in to directions when Rendering with VAO

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So here A screenshot of whats happening.

[image]

Also here is the method that makes the vao

```
public boolean create(float[] modelData) {

        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(modelData.length);
        buffer.put(modelData);
        buffer.flip();

        vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        vboID = glGenBuffers();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        vertexCount = modelData.length / 3;

        return true;

    }
```

and the one that adds the uv coords

```
public void addUV(float[] uv) {

        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(uv.length);
        buffer.put(uv);
        buffer.flip();

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        uvCoordLoc = glGetAttribLocation(shade.getProgramID(), "uv");

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvCoordLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(uvCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, buffer);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvCoordLoc);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }
```

and finally the one that renders.

```
    public void draw(int texID) {

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

        int texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shade.getProgramID(), "tex");
        glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);


        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvCoordLoc);

        shade.start();
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertexCount);
        shade.stop();

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvCoordLoc);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    }
```

And my shaders
vertex shader

```
#version 130

out vec4 theColor;
out vec2 uvCoord;

in vec2 uv;

void main() {   

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    theColor = gl_Position;

    uvCoord = uv;

}
```

fragment shader.

```
#version 130

in vec4 theColor;
in vec2 uvCoord;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture(tex, uvCoord).rgba;

}
```

I've tried messing with the uv coords but this is I've gotten so far.

and the model data and uv coords

```
        Model model = new Model();
        model.create(new float[] {
            -0.5f,-0.5f,-2f,
            -0.5f,0.5f,-2f,
            0.5f,0.5f,-2f,
            0.5f,-0.5f,-2f
        });
        model.addUV(new float[] {
                0,1,
                0,0,
                1,0,
                1,1
        });
```

any help would be nice

Answer (score 1):

When the image is loaded to a texture object, then [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) has to be set to 1.
By default `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is 4, so each line of an image is assumed to be aligned to 4 bytes. If the size of a pixel in the image is not a multiple of 4, (e.g. `GL_RGB` or `GL_RED)`, then this would cause a misalignment.

```java
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(...);
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tyQmsBX this is the result of doing that and sorry for taking so long to get back to you